Using the name of file select by user into a dictionary in python
I have a basic code, and essentially what I am trying to do is ask user to select a file. The goal is to save the name of that file as a "value", and use it into a dictionary.
The code is below:
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def select_study_file():
    study = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir=cur_dir, title='Select Study case')
    study = os.path.basename(study)
select_study_file()

config_dic = {"study_case" : study}

The expected output is:
config_dic = {"study_case" : "Name_of_the_file_selected}

What is your question?

@ScottHunter The question is how to get the name of the file selected by user, and use it as a value in the dictionary?

The function should end with return study, then you can use study = select_study_file()

@Barmar return study, and calling study again does work. Thank you for your help!

If you want fewer modifications yo your code, you can just add global study at the start of the function. That is a useful approach if you are going to have a button called that function later on.

You have a few errors in your code
you can try something like this
import os
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def select_study_file():
    study = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir=".", title="Select Study case")
    return os.path.basename(study)

study_file = select_study_file()
config_dic = {"study_case": study_file}

print(config_dic)  

